# Cannot sign in to MS services on Fedora 25 with PPPoE

Tags: fedora, windows, skype

I am on Fedora 25 and use the latest Skype for Linux. I have two ISPs - 1st one is ADSL and 2nd one is Broadband (PPPoE). On the 1st one, I have no problem signing in to Skype, but on the 2nd one I cannot sign in at all. When I type my password and click on "Sign in", nothing happens. Same with Hotmail, with the exception that there it looks like the system is starting to sign me in (the login page disappears), but after that - nothing.

On the same machine I also have Windows 7 (dual-boot), and there everything works fine with no problems on the Broadband connection. I already posted the question in Microsoft's Skype forum, but they advised me to call my ISP and ask them. I want to keep this as a last option, since it seems to be a problem with either Skype for Linux or Fedora 25.

Any help?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so it turns out the problem was a wrong MTU size, configured in Fedora. I fixed it according to the instructions [here](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/94426/wrong-mtu-for-pppoe/). Now everything works fine.